# How can I replace the OR condition in HIVE Join

Tags: hive, hiveql, impala, bigdata

I have the below 2 tables

```
Employee(age,name,dpt_cd,dpt_rg_cd)
Department(dpt_id,dpt_cd,dpt_rg_cd)
```

I want to perform the below query on these tables, but unfortunately HIVE  doesn't support OR in JOIN condition. How can I rewrite the query without OR condition which gives the same result

```
SELECT * FROM employee LEFT OUTER JOIN department ON (employee.dpt_cd =department.dpt_cd OR (employee.dpt_cd ='' AND employee.dpt_rg_cd= employee.dpt_rg_cd ))
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve multiple equerry issue in hive use semi [left join](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins) ie

```
select x.*
from employee x
LEFT SEMI JOIN  department   b on (x.buyer_id= b.id )
LEFT SEMI JOIN  department   c on (x.seller_id= c.id )
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use your conditions in the where clause and put 1=1 in on clause. Like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM employee LEFT OUTER JOIN department ON ( 1=1) 
where employee.dpt_cd =department.dpt_cd OR 
      (employee.dpt_cd ='' AND employee.dpt_rg_cd= employee.dpt_rg_cd )
```

Comment: I just use it as dummy condition for returning true always in on clause. You can skip it if you want.

Comment: we are performing the outer join first and any rows coming from the outer join that doesn't have matched will have nulls in all columns . The we apply our where clause ans since we apply condition on null columns it will not work. Is this correct?

Comment: When you compare nulls result is always false. So those rows  will be filtered. That is what we expecte right?

Comment: ok Puneet...So this (1=1) is for applying the where condition on not null records . Thus the above query will give the same result as the query I posted?

Comment: I have tested the code...the result gives the same result of inner join

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The predicate `employee.dpt_cd = department.dpt_cd` will cause all potential matches to be rejected unless they have a non-null `department.dpt_cd` (in particular, one that matches `employee.dpt_cd`. This will entirely negate the `LEFT OUTER` nature of the join, and cause it to return the same results as an INNER (or equi-) JOIN, as noted by @user7328756.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write the query as two selects with a union all as follows:

```
select * from employee left outer join department on (employee.dpt_cd =department.dpt_cd)
union all
select * from employee left outer join department on (employee.dpt_rg_cd = employee.dpt_rg_cd) where employee.dpt_cd ='';
```

This may be a very slow query but should produce the result you want.

Comment: Thanks Finbarr....But the result will have duplicates for the records which are not satisfying the condition since we are using left outer joins in both the queries